# Websockify server + socket.io client

Tags: socket.io, websockify

Im trying to connect from a client using socket.io :

```
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
    </script>
```

to a server running websockify to translate websocket traffic to normal tcp, im running it using the latest releases and :

```
 ./run 8000 :5000
```

but this error ocurrs:

```
WebSocket server settings:
  - Listen on :8000
  - Flash security policy server
  - No SSL/TLS support (no cert file)
  - proxying from :8000 to :5000
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Nov/2015 21:23:46] code 405, message Method Not Allowed
```

from what i have read this happens if you send a POST request to a server that doesnt allow it, is this whats causing this error? is there any way to configure websockify to accept such request?

Comment: socket.io isn't plain websockets. Are you using a websockify variant that supports socket.io?

Comment: whops, just realized i have to use websock.js, thanks kanaka